# Is there a way to delete all databases (without given names) in PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I want to make a function to reset all the content and initialize my webapp. Since I have a couple of generated names databases I would like just to remove them all.

Is there a way to do something like `PouchDB.destroyAll()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IndexedDB: webkitGetDatabaseNames is removed from chrome
see -> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5725741740195840

Agree that isn't possible using PouchDB directly you can do it using the following.

```
export const deletePouchDB = async() =>{
    const dbs = await window.indexedDB.databases();
    dbs.forEach(db => {
        if (db.name.includes('_pouch_')) {
            window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Not supported in Firefox (till 84.0.2).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using PouchDB directly but you can do it using the following snippet:

```
indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = (e) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < e.target.result.length; i++){
    let db = e.target.result[i];
    if(db.startsWith('_pouch_')){
      indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db);
    }
  }
};
```

This assumes that you're using PouchDB with indexedDB in chrome. If this is not the case, you'll have to adapt the above code to work with whatever storage engine and browser/server you're using.

Comment: Do you know how to access websql? I need to use this for iOS support but I can't find the correct object.

Comment: I've never used websql, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing it the pouchy way by using the [PouchDB allDbs() plugin](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-all-dbs) because it works when different db adapters have been used.

For example

```
try {
   const dbs = PouchDB.allDbs();
   // dbs is an array of strings, e.g. ['mydb1', 'mydb2']
   // delete the databases by name or whatever.
} catch(err) {
}
```

The `destroy()` method is handy, see [Destroying a database](https://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html#destroying-a%E2%80%93database)

From a developer perspective, see [Deleting your local database](https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html#deleting-your-local-database)